# Nested ItemsControls optimizations

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, uwp

I have a question regarding nested collections usage in UWP apps with XAML/C#.
Let's say I have a list of items with multiple images in each.
I need to show a scrollable list with all of the images inside the item data.
So far I can see a solution to create GridView with ItemsTemplate that has ItemsControl inside it. But it seams very slow and not optimized solution.
Is there any better suggestion to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Without much context, I can only think of following :

1. You have a large amount of data to be displayed, but not all at once. In this case you should consider using [controls that support virtualization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc716879(v=vs.100).aspx#Controls).
2. Flattening the data source before binding it. This may improve the performance by a little.

---

**Update**

Here is how you can do it :

```
<ListViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding Posts}">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" />

                <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Photos}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <VirtualizingStackPanel />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Image Source="{Binding}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListViewItem>
```

Comment: Well, I believe I can't flatten data as it's like a Facebook post with multiple images attached. Regarding virualization, I do you it on the first-level list, but how to virtualize nested itemscontrol?

Comment: You don't really need to virtualize the nested `ItemsControl` as they won't be realized in the first place if they are outside of visible area. Unless you have a large photo album.

Comment: I've included an example on how it can be done in my answer.

Comment: The issue I have is that when using nested itemscontrols, the UI stutters while creating and layouting the items inside, even though each item is only a button with image. So overall scrolling performance is ugly( For example first an items appears, than it resizes to add all images inside, and this happens for each item. Is there a way, may be, to optimize this process, so that when I see an item inside ListView it is already completely layouted and ready?